# Library program in Python 3 (beginner) with psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

I need help with this program. I am making a program for a library in **Python 3** (***psycopg2***) and I am making my modules to handle my tables, I have already done the "**create**" module and I am doing the "**delete**" module, I need help to do it, the code used is the following:

This is my class ConnectioDB: *(it works to connect to my database in postgresql)*

```
class ConnectionDB:
    """Connection class."""

    bd = None
    cursor = None

    def __init__(self, **param):
        """Connection constructor."""
        try:
            self.db = connect(
                host = '127.0.0.1', # localhost
                user = 'postgres'
                password = #$#!#*
                database = 'national-library'
            )
            self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
        except Error as e:
            write_errors(e, 'Failed to connect to database')
```

with the following lines are used to **execute sql code**:

```
def execute_sql(
        self, 
        sentence_sql, 
        param=None, 
        write_in_db=True
    ):
        """Execute SQL code."""
        try:
            execute = self.cursor.execute(sentence_sql, param)
            if write_in_db:
                result =  self.db.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            write_errors(e, f"An error occurred while executing the SQL statement:\n\n{sentence_sql}\n")
            if write_in_db:
                self.db.rollback()
```

now this is my **Model class** that has the "**create**" module

```
class Model():
    """Generic model class."""

    table_name = None
    connection = ConnectionDB()

    def create(self):
        """Save in database."""
        table_name = self.table_name
        keys = ", ".join(self.__dict__.keys())
        values_placeholders = ", ".join(["%s" for i in range(len(self.__dict__.keys()))])
        values = self.__dict__.values()
        sql = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} ({keys}) VALUES ({values_placeholders})"

        self.connection.execute_sql(sql, tuple(values))
```

I was trying to do the following code for my "**delete**" module but I'm not sure if it's ok:

```
 def delete(self, column_id):
        """Delete an item in the database."""
        table_name = self.table_name
        sql = f"DELETE FROM {table_name} WHERE id = %s"

        self.connection.execute_sql(sql, (column_id, ))
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: You should use [psycopg2.sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html), string formatting SQL statements often fails. You can easily adapt from there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61932040/7216865

Comment: I will try that thanks