# how to safely add postgreSQL records given a list of attributes in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm looking to implement a function that can add PostgreSQL records safely. Here's what I have:

```
def add_record_improved(table_name, lst_of_attributes):
    try:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO {} VALUES (%s)".format(sql.Identifier(table_name)), lst_of_attributes)
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
        print(cursor.fetchall())
    except Exception:
        print("ERROR: ILLEGAL VALUE - User Table")
        print(sys.exc_info()[1])
```

A typical use would for example be the call: add_record_improved("users", [username1, 21, Football])

However, I currently get an error that says:

"not all arguments converted during string formatting"

I don't know what exactly is wrong. I have looked at the documentation but can't figure it out. I will still link it here:

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyscopg2: Is it possible to dynamically add %s in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922540/pyscopg2-is-it-possible-to-dynamically-add-s-in-loop)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `lst_of_attributes` as params but you need to provide as many %s in the query string

```
in_str = ','.join(['%s'] * len(lst_of_attributes))  # This will generate a list '%s,%s,%s...'

query = "INSERT INTO {} VALUES ({})".format(sql.Identifier(table_name), in_str)

cursor.execute(query, params=lst_of_attributes)
```

As an example with `lst_of_attributes = [1, 2, 3]`, the query would look like

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", lst_attributes)
```

Also, please note that this isn't a complete solution and you need to wrap %s with quotes "" for charfields, but the solution is a staring point for you to work with.

Edit: Ignore previous sentence. As suggested by Richard, pyscopg handles the params

Comment: You do NOT need to wrap the %s with quotes. the whole point of psycopg's parameters is to handle that for you

Comment: Cool, I wasnt aware. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
cursor.execute(sql.SQL("insert into {} values (%s, %s, %s)").format(sql.Identifier(table_name)), lst_of_attributes)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: The number of attributes passed with lst_of_attributes should be general. I'm looking to use the function to add to multiple tables. But thank you for the suggestion.