# psycopg2 prepared delete statement

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am struggling with generating the delete query where parameters for the query is actually a set of values.

So I need to delete rows where parameters are a pair values for example:

`delete from table where col1 = %s and col2 = %s`

which can be executed in Python like:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(query, (col1_value, col2_value))
```

Now I would like to run a query:

```
delete from table where (col1, col2) in ( (col1_value1, col2_value1), (col1_value2, col2_value2) );
```

I can generate the queries and values and execute the exact SQL but I can't quite generate prepared statement.

I tried:

```
delete from table where (col1, col2) in %s
```

and

```
delete from table where (col1, col2) in (%s)
```

But when I try to execute:

```
cur.execute(query, list_of_col_value_tuples)
```

or

```
cur.execute(query, tuple_of_col_value_tuples)
```

I get an exception that indicates that psycopg2 cannot convert arguments to strings.

Is there any way to use psycopg2 to execute a query like this?

Comment: whats the exception?

Comment: Actually I resolved it.  Will add the add the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the resolution is quite easy if carefully constructed.

In the [miscellaneous goodies of psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html) there is a function `execute_values`.

While all the examples that are given by psycopg2 deal with inserts as the function basically converts the list of arguments into a `VALUES` list if the call to delete is formatted like so:

```
qry = "delete from table where (col1, col2) in (%s)"
```

The call:

```
execute_values(cur=cur, qry=qry, argslist=<list of value tuples>)
```

will make the delete perform exactly as required.

Answer (score 1):

You could dynamically add `%s` placeholders to your query:

```
cur = con.cursor()

query = "delete from table where (role, username) in (%s)"
options = [('admin', 'foo'), ('user', 'bar')]

placeholders = '%s,' * len(options)
query = query % placeholders[:-1]  # remove last comma
print(query)
print(cur.mogrify(query, options).decode('utf-8'))
```

Out:

```
delete from table where (role, user) in (%s,%s)
delete from table where (role, user) in (('admin', 'foo'),('user', 'bar'))
```

Alternatively, build the query using `psycopg2.sql` as answered [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922540/pyscopg2-is-it-possible-to-dynamically-add-s-in-loop/61932040#61932040).