# Psycopg2 query with both sequential and non-sequential parameters

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to run a query that uses variable substitution for both single variables and a sequence of variables. Here is a simplification of the kind of query I want to run:

```
SELECT 
    t.geography_id,
    t.source_id,
    t.target_date
FROM (VALUES %s) AS t(geography_id, source_id, target_date)
UNION
SELECT
    my_table.geography_id,
    my_table.source_id,
    my_table.target_date
FROM my_table where my_table.target_date = %s
```

With arguments `[(1, 4, date(2021, 1, 1)), (2, 5, date(2021, 1, 2))], date(2021, 1, 3)` (a list of tuples and then a date), I would want the resulting query to look like this after variable substitution:

```
SELECT 
    t.geography_id,
    t.source_id,
    t.target_date
FROM (VALUES (1, 4, '2021-01-01'::date),
     (2, 5, '2021-01-02'::date)) AS t(geography_id, source_id, target_date)
UNION
SELECT
    my_table.geography_id,
    my_table.source_id,
    my_table.target_date
FROM my_table where my_table.target_date = '2021-01-03'::date
```

#### What does not work

I can accomplish the first part of the query using `execute_values` like so:

```
sql = """
    SELECT 
        t.geography_id,
        t.source_id,
        t.target_date
    FROM (VALUES %s) AS t(geography_id, source_id, target_date)
"""

argslist = [(1, 4, date(2021, 1, 1)), (2, 5, date(2021, 1, 2))]

execute_values(cur, sql, argslist)
```

However, the [execute_values documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values) says that the `sql` argument "must contain a single %s placeholder, which will be replaced by a VALUES list", which means I cannot add the other part of my query.

I also tried out the `execute_batch` method, but it seems to run a separate statement for each item in the list, so it does not return the complete result I expected.

#### What does work

What does work is using AsIs to turn my sequential argument into a string to pass into a regular `execute` call. However, I'm reluctant to use this because then I have to worry about escaping, sanitizing, data type conversion, etc.

So I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this with the pyscopg2 methods or if I will need to restructure or split up my query. Thanks in advance for any insight you might have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [psycopg2 prepared delete statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66768703/psycopg2-prepared-delete-statement), have a look at my answer there.

Comment: Thank you, that helped!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing, with help from Maurice's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67100008/psycopg2-query-with-both-sequential-and-non-sequential-parameters#comment118616343_67100008):

```
query_template = """
    SELECT 
       t.geography_id,
        t.source_id,
        t.target_date
    FROM (VALUES ({}) AS t(geography_id, source_id, target_date)
    UNION
    SELECT
        my_table.geography_id,
        my_table.source_id,
        my_table.target_date
    FROM my_table where my_table.target_date = %s
"""

argslist = [(1, 4, date(2021, 1, 1)), (2, 5, date(2021, 1, 2))]

# Replace "{}" in query template with placeholders for argslist values
query = sql.SQL(query_template).format(
    sql.SQL('), (').join(
        (sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Placeholder() * len(argslist[0]))) * (
            len(argslist))))

# Flatten argslist for query arguments
query_args = [value for row in skip_table for value in row]
query_args.append(date(2021, 1, 3))

query_string = query.as_string(con)
cur.execute(query_string, query_args)
```